# Convert 2d array to mat3b

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an array of doubles ranging from 0 to 1. I can convert them to a `mat1d`, but I need a `mat3b`.

What I have so far is:

```cpp
    double snapgrid[132][177];
    //stuff in here to populate snapgrid
    Mat1d image(132, 177);
    memcpy(image.data, snapgrid, 132 * 177 * sizeof(double));
    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display window", image);
    waitKey(0);
```

This works and shows me the created image. Another function I'm trying to use next requires that image to be a `Mat3b`. I've tried a few methods of using `image.convertTo`, but am missing something. Any advice would be great.

edit:
I got it to not fault out, and I got my black image to improve by multiplying in the `convertTo`, so I think I'm there.

What I now have is:

```cpp
    double snapgrid[132][177];
    //stuff in here to populate snapgrid
    Mat1d image(132, 177);
    Mat colorImage;
    memcpy(image.data, snapgrid, 132 * 177 * sizeof(double));
    image.convertTo(colorImage, CV_32F, 255.);
    cvtColor(colorImage, colorImage, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display window", colorImage);
    waitKey(0);
```

My last question with this is: Is this the efficient way, or is this more of a slapped-together mess like I'm afraid it must look?

Comment: Does this `Mat3b` constructor work? https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/dfc/classcv_1_1Mat__.html#a276b9680948ebd82e3d8a7c1fa77af3c

Comment: It very well might, but I'm having difficulty understanding where I'd be dropping snapgrid into this command, and determining what format comes out of it.  I'm very new to not only c++ but also opencv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edit in my original post is enough to keep me moving, and so I'm going to call this case closed.